# google java api - is there a NearBySearch method?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-places

I know there's a web service for performing a nearby search but is there an equivalent method in the one of the java API's?

I'm trying to search for nearby places that match a given name so that I may mark them on a map. Closest I have found, with the java API's, is to use `getAutocompletePredictions` which gives the placeId. Using that, I can get the location. That's potentially a lot of separate requests.

Can anyone help/advise?

Comment: If you're going to downvote please have the decency to explain how I can  improve my question so as to avoid wasting peoples time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Places API for Android doesn't have this functionality yet. You can see a corresponding feature request in Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37530354

Feel free to add star to this feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications.

In the meantime you should use Places API web service in order to do nearby and text searches. There is a *Java Client for Google Maps Services* that you can find on github:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

I would suggest trying this library. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer. I was expecting a flood of anonymous down votes! I have reverted to using the web service in the mean time and all is working well.